# Regex vowels in order but not all vowels?

Tags: regex

I know there are similar questions, however the last question only stated if a word has all of the vowels in the word.  What I am trying to do is find if a word has its vowels in alphabetical order.  For example the words: almost, various, etc.

I have tried many different solutions however I cannot get to this work.

Things like:

```
(a[^eiou]*)?(e[^aiou]*)?(i[^aeou]*)?(o[^aeio]*u)?
```

and

```
a[^eiou]*e[^aiou]*i[^aeou]*o[^aeio]*u
```

but these do not work.

Comment: Well this screams of homework. Does your teacher require all of the seaching be done by regular expressions? or can you also use another language in conjuntion with it?

Comment: this is not homework, this is exam revision, my teacher requires nothing of me, i am just looking over past exam papers without solutions. and not i must be only regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first try is not too far, try this:

```
\b[^aeiou]*(?:a[^eiou]*)?(?:e[^aiou]*)?(?:i[^aeou]*)?(?:o[^aeiu]*)?u?[^aeio]*\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u298).

I added:

`\b` word boundaries to ensure that the complete word is matched

`[^aeiou]*` at the beginning to match non vowels before the first "a"

`(?:o[^aeio]*)?u?` changed the last part a bit to make the "o" optional

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis a fixed it, also the Regexr link is updated

Comment: @stema the link seems to have disappeared, but +1 for a working pattern.

Comment: is that saying the first letter cant be a vowel?

Comment: * means 0 or more instances, so no.

Comment: oh actually, this works on a regex tester, but i cant seem to get my escaping right to work it on a grep command in unix :(

Comment: also, it doesn't match words such as hail, and ale, etc :O

Comment: @exclu: You need to use `pcregrep`, not normal `grep`.  Normal `grep` is not powerful enough.

Comment: @exclu: `hail` and `ale` both get matched in the tester.

Answer (score 0):

How about `\b[^aeiou]*a*[^eiou]*e*[^aiou]*i*[^aeou]o*[^aeiu]*u*[^aeio]*\b`.

Comment: seems to match words that dont have vowels in them also :S

Comment: I would say that technically those words do not violate the constraint that all vowels are in order because there are no vowels to make it not work. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Answer (score 0):

Here's my bid:

```
^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*?(?:a[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*?)?(?:e[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*?)?(?:i[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*?)?(?:o[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*?)?(?:u[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*?)?$
```

Can also bind by word separators (`\b`) but seems to [pass my testing](http://regexr.com?2u29b).